# Power BI - Circular Dependency Issues. 2 calculated columns referencing each other

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a calculated table that looks like this

| Project | Completed Through | Totally Completed | Expected Completion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Proj 1 | 15 |  |  |
| Proj 2 | 52 |  |  |
| Proj 3 | 35 |  |  |
| Proj 4 | 23 |  |  |
| Proj 5 | 23 |  |  |

Partially Completed & Expected Completion are 2 columns I need to calculate which reference on another

Totally Completed: Completed Through - Expected Completion

Expected Completion:  Totally Completed - Completed Through

I am looking for a workaround on how I can get around the curcular dependency issue I'm having

Answer (score 0):

You can't: **It's not a technical problem but a logical.**
When you rearrange your to your equations the result is:

```
'Table'[Expected Completion] = - 'Table'[Expected Completion]
```

That's impossible. [Understanding circular dependencies in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-circular-dependencies/) has more information on this topic, but the bottom line is:

*"A model containing circular dependencies cannot be processed until the developer removes them entirely from the dependency chart. It is as simple as that."*

Sometimes circular dependencies are difficult to spot. The above article has valuable tips on how to find them, when it's less obvious than in your case.

Comment: I understand that  this is a logical problem, I'm just wondering how people may have overcome this (if anyone has encountered this previously)